# How do I get UserCreationForm data displayed in the django admin and on my template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a django app that extends the user model to include more fields that collect data about a new user. So far I have managed to get the form to work properly and render the fields on a template correctly.

I'm also trying to add the new user to a group called `agents`, which I have somehow achieved, but on adding the new user to the `agents` user group I run into a problem on the templates where I want to display all the new user information as stored in the database. The usual django user fields e.g `email, name` are accessible but the additional form fields I created are not displayed. Below is my code:

**forms.py**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
COUNTIES = (('Baringo','Baringo'),
           ('Bomet','Bomet'),
           ('Bungoma', 'Bungoma'),
          )
first_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
last_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
photo = forms.ImageField()
email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
company = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
county = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTIES)
city = forms.CharField(required = True)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2') 

    def clean_email(self):
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email

        # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')

def save(self,commit = True):   
    user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.photo = self.cleaned_data['photo']
    user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
    user.company = self.cleaned_data['company']
    user.county = self.cleaned_data['county']
    user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)     # create form object
    if user_form.is_valid():
        # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password2'])
        # Save the User object

        new_user.save()
        my_group = Group.objects.get(name='agents') 
        my_group.user_set.add(new_user)

        return render(request, 'administration/register.html', {'user_form':user_form})

else:
    user_form = MyRegistrationForm()
return render(request,'administration/register.html',{'user_form':user_form})
```

**Template**

```
{% for agent in agents %}
<tr>
<td>
    {% thumbnail agent.photo "50x50" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" class="img-responsive table-img"> {% empty %}
    <img src="{% static 'dashboard/assets/img/default-avatar.png' %}" class="img-responsive table-img" alt=""> {% endthumbnail %}
</td>
<td>{{ agent.first_name }} {{ agent.last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ agent.company }} </td>
<td>{{ agent.phone }}</td>
<td>{{ agent.email }}</td>
<td class="td-actions text-right">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Task" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
</td>
   </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can't just add fields to the form, you need fields to store them in the model.

Comment: Looking at my code how can i do that? i am a beginner so im pretty much confused here?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model